# Получить свойства с их значениями в ORM Laravel

Tags: база-данных, laravel, orm

Каким образом можно получить свойства товаров с их значениями (используя ORM) при следующей структуре таблиц:

```
products (id, name)
product_properties (id, name)
product_property_values (id, product_property_id, product_id, value)
```

Написал метод "properties" в модели товара "Product":

```
public function properties()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\ProductProperty',
        'App\Models\ProductPropertyValue',
        'product_id',
        'id',
        'id',
        'product_property_id'
    );
}
```

Он возвращает такие данные:

```
[
    [
        'id' => 1, 
        'name' => 'Название товара',
        'properties' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Название свойства',
            'product_id' => 1
        ]
    ], 
    ...
]
```

Нужно в массив свойств добавить ещё значение свойства по ключу "value" к примеру.

P.S. Существующие модели: "App\Models\Product", "App\Models\ProductProperty" и "App\Models\ProductPropertyValue".

Answer (score 0):

В общем получилось сделать, правда не совсем так как я хотел, но всё же...

Реализовал отношение в модели "ProductPropertyValue":

```
/**
 * Получает привязанное свойство.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function property()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ProductProperty', 'product_property_id', 'id');
}
```

В модели "Product" отношение выглядит так:

```
/**
 * Получает привязанные свойства с их значениями.
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function properties()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductPropertyValue')->with('property');
}
```

В итоге получилась следующая структура:

```html
array:6 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "name" => "Название товара"
  "code" => "Символьный код товара"
  "created_at" => "2017-10-22 10:36:57"
  "updated_at" => "2017-10-22 10:36:59"
  "properties" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 7
      "product_property_id" => 6
      "product_id" => 1
      "value" => "Значение свойства"
      "created_at" => "2017-10-29 16:03:55"
      "updated_at" => "2017-10-29 16:04:10"
      "property" => array:5 [▼
        "id" => 6
        "name" => "Название свойства"
        "code" => "Символьный код свойства"
        "created_at" => "2017-10-29 15:53:09"
        "updated_at" => "2017-10-29 15:53:10"
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:7 [▶]
  ]
]
```